# privateKey in keystore is returning null

Tags: spring-boot, junit4, junit5

```java
public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(KeyStore keystore, String keyId, char[] keyPwd) throws BenefitsException {
  PrivateKey privateKey = null;
  try {
    if (keystore == null || keyPwd == null || keyId == null || "".equals(keyId)) {
      return privateKey;
    } else {
      privateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(keyId, keyPwd);
    }
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableKeyException | KeyStoreException e) {
    throw new BenefitsException("Error in getPrivateKey method : ", e);
  }
  return privateKey;
}
```

This is my test method. Does anyone figure out why privatekey is returning `null`?

```java
@Test 
public void getPrivateKey_ExceptionTest() throws Exception {
  KeyStore keystoreMock = Mockito.mock(KeyStore.class);

  FieldUtils.writeField(keystoreMock, "keyStoreSpi", Mockito.mock(KeyStoreSpi.class), true);
  FieldUtils.writeField(keystoreMock, "initialized", true, true);

  char[] pwd = {'c', 'h', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e', 'i', 't'};

  cryptoUtils.getPrivateKey(keystoreMock, "somestring", pwd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is because you don't [stub](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2) the `getKey` method on your `keyStoreMock`, so you get the default answer `null`.

Try something like:

```java
String keyId = "keyId";
char[] keyPwd = {'c', 'h', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e', 'i', 't'};
PrivateKey expectedPrivateKey = /* ... */
Mockito.when(keystoreMock.getKey(keyId, keyPwd).thenReturn(expectedPrivateKey);
```